# Finding Ellipse equation from 3 points

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, elliptic-equations

I have 3 points

```
f1: (6,0)      // Foci point
f2: (-6,0)     // Foci point
p:  (8.1, 4.7) // point on the ellipse
```

Ellipse equation is:
$$ \frac{x^{2}}{a^2}+\frac{y^{2}}{b^2}=1 $$

How do I find $ a $ and $b$?

[image]

Comment: You don't have $3$ points but $2$ because of symmetry. Anyway, this is enough to obtain the two parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

use the fact that if the foci of the ellipse are $F=(\pm c,0)$ than [we have](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Ellipse_in_Cartesian_coordinates) $b^2+c^2=a^2$.  So you have only one free parameter in the equation that can be determined using the coordinates of the given point.

---

e have $c=6$,  so: $a^2=36+b^2$ and the equation of the ellipse becomes:
$$
\frac{x^2}{36+b^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1
$$
substitute $x=8.1$ and $y=4.7$ and solve the equation for $b^2$.

Comment: Thanks, so we have $b$ by $b=\sqrt{a^2 - c^2}$. An we got $a$ from Arjang answer $a=\frac{d(f_1,p)+d(f_2,p)}{2}$.

Comment: I've added to my answer. Can you do from here?

Comment: Yes, I've solved it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let $d(p_1,p_2)$ mean distance between points $p_1$ and $p_2$ then we have
$d(f_1,p)+d(f_2,p)=2a$,

then use the steps from [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ellipse.html) to find b.

Comment: I think it might be better if your answer were self-contained instead of linking to another site.

Comment: @amd : hmm, if somebody cant follow these stupidly simple steps to learn how to learn then there is no hope for them. Teaching how to do it, not doing for them.

Comment: External links go stale. It’s considered bad practice on MSE for the bulk of your answer to be a page on some other site. You’re not just providing an answer for this particular user. This answer must be usable by anyone who comes along later, too.

Comment: @amd : mathworld has been there since time immemrial, if that page goes stale then internet is likely finished, it is from wolfram

Comment: @Arjang thanks, but the reason I'm asking this is not educational. I'm implementing a program (similar to SolidWorks or AutoCAD3D but simpler) where the user can draw 3D shapes only by dragging points.
I already implemented splines but wanted to have ellipical arcs too ...

Anyway thanks good link, So I can get $a$ with $a=\frac{d(f_1,p)+d(f_2,p)}{2}$.
And $b$ from Emilio Novati answer with $b=\sqrt{a^2 - c^2}$

Comment: @Mustafa step (9) of that link shows that what b is, not sure what is so hard about it, I got the 2a from step (1) of that link